# How to consume a Servicestack.net rest method with IreturnVoid

Tags: servicestack

I am implementing some of the new API features of ServiceStack, specifically trying to use `IReturnVoid`. I am consuming the service in Monotouch, but all the clients expect a response type.

Is this just a matter of the Monotouch API getting updated to support the `IReturnVoid` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **client.SendOneWay()** method.

The MonoTouch / MonoDroid libraries are a little behind the full release, something we hope to rectify soon.

Comment: Any ETA? I wish I would have found ServiceStack sooner. Keep up the great work.

Comment: Contributions to the MonoTouch/MonoDroid clients were added a couple of days ago :) https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/301